# Specify which frame to render in blender terminal

Tags: command-line

I want to render a selected few frames in blender from terminal. From [blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#animation-playback-options), it has options to set start and end frame, but no option to specify individual frame numbers. Is there a way to specify that?

I can run rendering multiple times, once for each frame by setting start and end frame to the specified frame number. I am looking if it is possible to do it in a single command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Render Arguments](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#render-options) section of that page describes `--render-frame`. That's the option you are looking for.

`--render-frame <frame>`

- Render frame `<frame>` and save it.

  - + start frame relative, - end frame relative.
  - A comma separated list of frames can also be used (no spaces).
  - A range of frames can be expressed using .. separator between the first and last frames (inclusive).

`-f` is the short form of the arguments.  Here are some examples, assuming you have your start and end frame set to 1 and 250, the defaults:

- `-f 7` renders frame 7;
- `-f +7` renders frame 8;
- `-f -1` renders frame 249;
- `-f 3,5,7` renders frames 3, 5, and 7; and
- `-f 3..7` renders frames 3 through 7